# The office web apps doesnt reflect updated internal URL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, server, owa

I have updated the internal and external url for the office web apps farm, but the office web apps preview in the sharepoint web application still points to the old URL of the Office web apps farm, I have reset the IIS of the Office web apps farm as well, but the change doesn't reflect. Is there a dependency on something for the change to take affect?

The old Url was in the format https://servername.abc.def.gef

The new url is a FQDN https://webapplication.domain

I have checked with /hosting/discovery and the OWA still works on the old URL. When i run Get-officewebappsfarm   I see the https://webapplication.domain as my internal and external address ,  but the https://servername.abc.def.gef/hosting/discovery  return the XML and https://webapplication.domain/hosting/discovery doesnt return anything.

The preview in my webapp uses the link https://servername.abc.def.gef as a reference, whereas I have updated it to https://webapplication.domain.

I have reset the IIS of the Office web apps farm a couple of time as well.

Any ideas about this.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the URL's doesn't take effect until every server in the farm is restarted. So instead of restarting every server I did the following to resolve the issue

1) Removed OWA bindings from the SharePoint farm

2) Removed OfficeWebAppsMachine from the OWA farm

3) Restarted the OWA server

4) Reconfigured the OWA farm with the new URL

5) Reconfigured the Bindings

And Voila you get the desired output.